# Apple rejected application with facebook login in a application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store-connect

Following are the response  I have a got from apple. When I have live iOS application, I am not getting whats the actual issue, and facebook login is working fine from my device with latest iOS device.

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone and iPad running iOS 11.2.2 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.

Facebook log in is not operational.

The steps to reproduce are:
1. Launch the app
2. Tap on Sign In with Facebook > Continue
3. The app takes the user back to the registration screen without logging in.

Comment: try to login with someone else account, you will get the issue. For you its working because you are the app owner in facebook...

Comment: Following are not the I have a got code from you when I read your post, I am not getting whats the actual issue.

Comment: Application rejected issue.

Answer (score 0):

i got this response many times..do this steps:

1. add CFNetwork.framework in your app..
2. clean, rebuild and reupload new build with changes..and send them in apple review process.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i am able to login with Facebook without CFNetwork.framework and with IPv6 network(NAT64 Networks). I want to know whats the actual bugs for rejection.

Comment: actually..apple is completely testing on ipv6 network..may be your network provide is not completely ipv6 network..so this bug is specifically for network point..your app is not getting internet so its endless loading..

Comment: It will be possible for approved application by apple after add this CFNetwork.framework.

Comment: My deployment target is 9.0 so why is return 70000 in __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED.

Comment: I have a review AFNetworkReachabilityManager class and print log in + (instancetype)manager
{
    NSLog(@"min iphoneos: %i - %i",__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED,__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED);

#if (defined(__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 90000) || (defined(__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED) && __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 101100)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163858/discussion-between-iosdev-and-stranger).